Section number and title spacing in references
I am using the following code to reduce the space between the section number and the section title:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} 

\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={red!50!black}, citecolor={blue!50!black}, urlcolor={blue!80!black}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.\hspace{-0.4cm}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\hspace{-0.35cm}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\hspace{-0.3cm}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\label{subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Text \Cref{subsection}. More text.

\end{document}

However, the reference gets overlapped with the text. Is there a way around this? Or should I use something else to change the spacing?

Don't modify \thesection etc. but use a package like titlesec or a more configurable class like memoir or scrartcl to change the formatting of section number and title in the section heads
